# Is this high-vote close-bait question of mine a good candidate for the prestigious "locked" status?

Tags: discussion

ref: [What is the history of considering Rock 'n' Roll to be "the Devil's music"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9779/is-rock-n-roll-the-devils-music)

Meta SO has a [list of fun, deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-so-su-programmers-questions-list) that only 10k+ users can see, but there is a suggestion that these be undeleted and labeled with the big 'LOCKED' warning.

So, the trend appears to be to go straight to *locked*. Which is a consolation prize for borderline questions. It's here. It's kind of interesting. Don't do it again.

So, is my question a good fit for our own list of Good *Bad* Questions?

Comment: I thought it was questionable, but my flag asking the other mods what they thought was declined :P

Comment: I flagged it asking for CW, then I remembered all your posts about CW, and tried to flag again to retract it. Not sure if the second went through but the first was declined. I knew it was shaky territory.

Comment: Those questions are humorous. Your question didn't strike me as humorous (or on-topic for that matter). It also seemed pretty subjective.